# Output files returned after training a alexnet model...?

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network, tflearn

Code is written in Python 3.5.X

**Please try to make the answer simple for a 3rd year Computer Science Student**

The output files from train_model.py seems to be a model.meta file but the test_model.py is asking for a .model file. The tutorial user has a .model file as well I can't seem to understand why i am getting a file with .model.meta

I am trying to play GTA San Andreas through Python or more precisely the car in GTA is driven by the model.
It takes screen frames as Input and recorded the key i Input during training. This training data is used to train the model.

**Code for training the model**

```
import numpy as np
from alexnet import alexnet

WIDTH = 80
HEIGHT = 60
LR = 1e-3
EPOCHS = 8
MODEL_NAME = 'pygta_sa-car-{}-{}-{}-epochs.model'.format(LR, 'alextnetv2', EPOCHS)

model = alexnet(WIDTH, HEIGHT, LR)

train_data = np.load('training_data_v2.npy')

train = train_data[:-500]
test = train_data[-500:]

X = np.array([i[0] for i in train]).reshape(-1,WIDTH,HEIGHT,1)
Y = [i[1] for i in train]

test_x = np.array([i[0] for i in test]).reshape(-1,WIDTH,HEIGHT,1)
test_y = [i[1] for i in test]

model.fit({'input': X}, {'targets': Y}, n_epoch=EPOCHS, validation_set=({'input': test_x}, {'targets': test_y}), 
    snapshot_step=500, show_metric=True, run_id=MODEL_NAME)

# tensorboard --logdir=foo:F:\play_gta_sa\log

model.save(MODEL_NAME)
```

training completes successfully and returns files

[image]

Files returned on the video of the Tutorial i am using to do this project

[sent_dex files returned](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ciHC.png)

**Content of Checkpoint file**

model_checkpoint_path: "F:\play_gta_sa\pygta_sa-car-0.001-alextnetv2-8-epochs.model"
all_model_checkpoint_paths: "F:\play_gta_sa\pygta_sa-car-0.001-alextnetv2-8-epochs.model"

**Code for testing the model on the game**

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import time
from grabscreen import grab_screen
from getkeys import key_check
from directkeys import PressKey, ReleaseKey, W, A, S, D
from alexnet import alexnet


WIDTH = 80
HEIGHT = 60
LR = 1e-3
EPOCHS = 8
MODEL_NAME = 'pygta_sa-car-{}-{}-{}-epochs.model'.format(LR, 'alexnetv2',EPOCHS) 


def straight():
    PressKey(W)
    ReleaseKey(A)
    ReleaseKey(D)

def left():
    PressKey(W)
    PressKey(A)
    ReleaseKey(D)

def right():
    PressKey(W)
    PressKey(D)
    ReleaseKey(A)

model = alexnet(WIDTH, HEIGHT, LR)
model.load(MODEL_NAME)

def main():

    for i in list(range(10))[::-1]:
        print(i+1)
        time.sleep(1)

    last_time = time.time()

    paused = False

    while True:
        if not paused:

            screen = grab_screen(region=(0,40,800,640))
            screen = cv2.cvtColor(screen,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
            screen = cv2.resize(screen,(80,60))
            print('Frame took {} seconds'.format(time.time()-last_time))
            last_time = time.time()

            moves = list(np.around(model.predict([screen.reshape(80,60,1)])[0]))
            print(moves, prediction)

            if moves == [1,0,0]:
                left()
            elif moves == [0,1,0]:
                straight()
            elif moves == [0,0,1]:
                right()

        keys = key_check()

    # p pauses game and can get annoying.
        if 'T' in keys:
            if paused:
                paused = False
                time.sleep(1)
            else:
                paused = True
                ReleaseKey(A) 
                ReleaseKey(W)
                ReleaseKey(D)
                time.sleep(1)

main()
```

the error message on running test model

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1039, in _do_call
    return fn(*args)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1021, in _run_fn
    status, run_metadata)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\contextlib.py", line 66, in __exit__
    next(self.gen)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\errors_impl.py", line 466, in raise_exception_on_not_ok_status
    pywrap_tensorflow.TF_GetCode(status))
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: Unsuccessful TensorSliceReader constructor: Failed to find any matching files for F:\play_gta_sa\pygta_sa-car-0.001-alexnetv2-8-epochs.model
     [[Node: save_1/RestoreV2 = RestoreV2[dtypes=[DT_FLOAT], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](_recv_save_1/Const_0, save_1/RestoreV2/tensor_names, save_1/RestoreV2/shape_and_slices)]]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\play_gta_sa\test_model.py", line 33, in <module>
    model.load(MODEL_NAME)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\tflearn\models\dnn.py", line 282, in load
    self.trainer.restore(model_file, weights_only, **optargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\tflearn\helpers\trainer.py", line 452, in restore
    self.restorer.restore(self.session, model_file)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\saver.py", line 1457, in restore
    {self.saver_def.filename_tensor_name: save_path})
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 778, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 982, in _run
    feed_dict_string, options, run_metadata)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1032, in _do_run
    target_list, options, run_metadata)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1052, in _do_call
    raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: Unsuccessful TensorSliceReader constructor: Failed to find any matching files for F:\play_gta_sa\pygta_sa-car-0.001-alexnetv2-8-epochs.model
     [[Node: save_1/RestoreV2 = RestoreV2[dtypes=[DT_FLOAT], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](_recv_save_1/Const_0, save_1/RestoreV2/tensor_names, save_1/RestoreV2/shape_and_slices)]]

Caused by op 'save_1/RestoreV2', defined at:
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\idlelib\run.py", line 124, in main
    ret = method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\idlelib\run.py", line 351, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "F:\play_gta_sa\test_model.py", line 32, in <module>
    model = alexnet(WIDTH, HEIGHT, LR)
  File "F:\play_gta_sa\alexnet.py", line 40, in alexnet
    max_checkpoints=1, tensorboard_verbose=0, tensorboard_dir='log')
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\tflearn\models\dnn.py", line 64, in __init__
    best_val_accuracy=best_val_accuracy)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\tflearn\helpers\trainer.py", line 147, in __init__
    allow_empty=True)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\saver.py", line 1056, in __init__
    self.build()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\saver.py", line 1086, in build
    restore_sequentially=self._restore_sequentially)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\saver.py", line 691, in build
    restore_sequentially, reshape)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\saver.py", line 407, in _AddRestoreOps
    tensors = self.restore_op(filename_tensor, saveable, preferred_shard)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\saver.py", line 247, in restore_op
    [spec.tensor.dtype])[0])
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\gen_io_ops.py", line 669, in restore_v2
    dtypes=dtypes, name=name)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\op_def_library.py", line 768, in apply_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 2336, in create_op
    original_op=self._default_original_op, op_def=op_def)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 1228, in __init__
    self._traceback = _extract_stack()

NotFoundError (see above for traceback): Unsuccessful TensorSliceReader constructor: Failed to find any matching files for F:\play_gta_sa\pygta_sa-car-0.001-alexnetv2-8-epochs.model
     [[Node: save_1/RestoreV2 = RestoreV2[dtypes=[DT_FLOAT], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](_recv_save_1/Const_0, save_1/RestoreV2/tensor_names, save_1/RestoreV2/shape_and_slices)]]
```

Comment: Which version of Tensorflow are you using? Are the training and testing scripts both in the same directory? Can you confirm that besides the three files generated, there's still another file called checkpoint?

Comment: There's no problem regarding the filename of the three files you got. It is how TF save models. However, there seems to be some other problems regarding the error you got.

Comment: Tensorflow 1.1.0 tried both installations techniques namely pip install tensorflow and by whl file from unofficial binaries for windows site...and yes there is a checkpoint named file in the directory and both the scripts are im the same directory

Comment: Can you post the content of file checkpoint?

Comment: Plz update it in your post for better readibility.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the update.

### Edit:

Try add this line before `tf.reset_default_graph()` loading model. That is

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.reset_default_graph()
model = alexnet(WIDTH, HEIGHT, LR)
model.load(MODEL_NAME)
```

Comment: I trained a new model with epochs 15 so the checkpoint file contains the models name with epochs 15. I modify the test_model.py and try to run it though...

Comment: oh...can you provide a link to the alexnet package you are using?

Comment: This guy is applying in GTA V  i am applying in GTA SA but the code is total copy paste from this https://github.com/Sentdex/pygta5/tree/master/Tutorial%20Codes/Part%2014-15

Comment: How about reset the graph before loading it?

Comment: nope no effect still the same error message will upload the image of the .model file from the video tutorial to prove that the file extension is the problem...

Answer (score 0):

The crux of this error is:

```
Unsuccessful TensorSliceReader constructor: Failed to find any matching files for F:\play_gta_sa\pygta_sa-car-0.001-alexnetv2-8-epochs.model
```

Okay, so a typical "file not found." Are we confident that we have this file? Maybe, but, if it was there, it would have been found. Our first guess should be we've typoed or otherwise made a mistake. Let's look at your model files:

For training the model, you have:

```
MODEL_NAME = 'pygta_sa-car-{}-{}-{}-epochs.model'.format(LR, 'alextnetv2', EPOCHS)
```

For testing the model, you have:

```
MODEL_NAME = 'pygta_sa-car-{}-{}-{}-epochs.model'.format(LR, 'alexnetv2',EPOCHS)
```

Do you see difference yet? There's a typo. alextnetv2 vs alexnetv2

Fix that, and the file will at least be found.